# Intercept message generating JsonMappingException

Tags: json, web-services, jaxb, jackson, jax-rs

I need to store in my db all the JSON messages causing either a JsonMappingException or a JsonParseException processed using the Jackson library.

I have registered a custom ExceptionMapper for both but at the moment I can just send a response back to the client.

```
 public Response toResponse(JsonMappingException paramJsonMappingException)
  {
      return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
  }
```

Do you know if there is a way to retrieve it?